# I try to display next row on refresh but i get a blank page

Tags: php, sql

Hey I try to display next row on refresh and when it arrive at last row to take it from the beginning. Here is my table

```
col1 row(1)
col2 row(1)
col3 row(1)
col4 row(1)
col5 row(1)
```

and on refresh to get

```
col1 row(2)
col2 row(2)
col3 row(2)
col4 row(2)
col5 row(2)
```

and when it arrive at last row take it from the beginning.

```
col1 row(1)
col2 row(1)
col3 row(1)
col4 row(1)
col5 row(1)
```

Here is the code so far:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
    $_SESSION["id"] = $_SESSION["id"] + 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION["id"] = 1;
}

$id = $_SESSION["id"];

//Your mysql connection 

$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE `id` = $id") or die('AM error occured: ' . mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo $row["content0"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content1"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content2"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content3"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content4"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content5"];

}
```

Comment: I want to get each time i refresh the page the next row from the table.

Comment: you need pagination kind of thing

Comment: I need with refresh if it can be done

Comment: First, put session_start(); at the very top, above the config. And then try changing $_SESSION["id"] + 1; to $_SESSION["id"]++;

Comment: If you can help me with this it will be great i'm going crazy over this I just starting with PHP.

Comment: Are you sure that id does not have gaps, eg, id = 1,2,4,6... ?

Comment: Edited my answer, now it shows exactly as you want it, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
    $_SESSION["id"] = $_SESSION["id"] + 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION["id"] = 1;
}

$id = $_SESSION["id"];

//Your mysql connection 

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(id) as total from testtable");
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
if($data['total']<$id )
{
$_SESSION["id"] = 1;
    $id=1;
} 


$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE `id` = $id") or die('AM error occured: ' . mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo $row["content0"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content1"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content2"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content3"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content4"];
      echo "<br>";
    echo $row["content5"];

}
```

explanation:

here we are getting total records and checking with current refreshed item, if greater then that we are assigning to start(1)

Comment: Thanks very much ;)  Btw $result=mysqli_query("SELECT count(id) as total from testtable"); needs a connection :P $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(id) as total from testtable");  for future if someone needs it :)

Answer (score 0):

To get next id from the table if it has gaps in id values use this query

```
select * 
from testtable 
where id >= if($id > (select max(id) from testtable), 1, $id) 
order by id 
limit 1
```

and save in session variable selected id

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pagination, what can be done with $_SESSION. Next is an example with an array of data :

```
<?php
session_start();
// SAMPLE DATA.
$items = array( array( "a","b","c","d","e","f" ),
                array( "1","2","3","4","5","6" ),
                array( "+","-","*","/","&","#" )
              );

if ( ! isset( $_SESSION[ "current" ] ) ) // IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME.
     $_SESSION[ "current" ] = 0; // FIRST ITEM TO SHOW.
else if ( $_SESSION[ "current" ] < ( count( $items )-1 ) )
          $_SESSION[ "current" ] ++; // NEXT ROW.
     else $_SESSION[ "current" ] = 0; // FIRST ROW AGAIN.
?>
<html>
  <body>
    Showing items :
    <br/>
<?php
// DISPLAY CURRENT ROW.
foreach ( $items[ $_SESSION[ "current" ] ] as $item )
   echo $item . " row(" . $_SESSION[ "current" ] . ")<br/>";
?>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    -- Refresh to see next page --
  </body>
</html>
```

Copy-paste previous code in a PHP file and open it in your browser. Each time you refresh the page, the next block of items will be shown.

To adapt it to your code, we only need to **fill** the array of data with the sql query :

```
$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE `id` = $id")
           or die('AM error occured: ' . mysqli_error());
$items = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
  array_push( $items,array( $row["content0"],
                            $row["content1"],
                            $row["content2"],
                            $row["content3"],
                            $row["content4"],
                            $row["content5"] ) );
}
```